# How to install npm 3.10.8 on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: javascript, nodes, npm-install

I tried this command:

```
npm install npm@3.10.8
```

and I got this error:

> npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-21-generic
>
> npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "npm@3.10.8"
>
> npm ERR! node v4.2.6
>
> npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
>
> npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
>
> npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=socket hang up
>
> npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
>
> npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
>
> npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network 
>   settings.
>
> npm ERR! network
>
> npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
>
> npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>
> npm ERR!     /home/user/npm-debug.log

Comment: As it says, add Please include the following file with any support request:

/home/user/npm-debug.log, add it to http://pastebin.com/index.php. Don't paste here.

Answer (score -1):

The one that i use is from nodejs you can run the below code

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs
$ node -v
$ npm -v
```

There you go, you should be up and running! go to [Installing NodeJs](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/)